# Make price without 0 before, the lowest php mysqli

Tags: php, sorting, mysqli, decimal

So I just recently discovered when doing beta testing on my website that the prices without a 0 before them (09.00) is counted as 90 and not 9. So instead of having so that $9.00 would come before $19.00, it takes $19.00 as the lowest because $9.00 is recognized as $90.00. One solution is to put $09.00 instead of $9.00, however I find it highly ineffective and ugly quite frankly. Do you got any solutions?
This is a pick of how it turns out.. It's varchar, should I change it to something else (such as int?)

http://i.gyazo.com/7d1b7468142d4e5ce39849b269952591.png

I have this on my input number, where the user set his or hers price (it starts from 1 then adds  with decimals in the end...)

```
<input type="number" class="item-edit-audio-input" step="0.01" min="0" name="item-price" min="1" value="<?php echo $sound_price ?>"required>
```

Comment: why do you have dublicate attribute min? min="0" name="item-price" min="1" ?

Comment: Personally I would change this to `decimal` in the database. Secondly however you enter the products into the site, you need to do some validation/cleaning before inserting into the database. Thirdly why not create a function to clean the prices before being displayed therefore catching issues on both sides. Having $09.00 even be allowed into your  DB I would say, is the issue here.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat I mean, I can strip the 0  away upon displaying the price, so secretly it would order it as 09, but display it as 9. But it would be ineffective for the user that's posting with the price. 

And MihaiZinculescu, just noticed..